# Django Forms: Validation forms error when apply two validations

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with `'start=forms.DateInput'`, `end=forms.DateInput` and `active=forms.CheckboxInput`, but when I try to validate this fields, I have these errors.

```
KeyError at /employee/edit/70000007/
'end'
```

...

```
if form.is_valid():
```

...

```
end = self.cleaned_data['end']
```

But this works fine when apply only one validator.

```
def clean_end(self):
    start = self.cleaned_data['start']
    end = self.cleaned_data['end']
    if end < start:
        raise forms.ValidationError('end date cannot be less than start date.')       
    return end

def clean_active(self):
    active = self.cleaned_data['active']
    end = self.cleaned_data['end']
    if active and end:
        raise forms.ValidationError('active employee should cannot be end date')
    return active
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your validation code requires the data from more than one field it should be be in the form's `clean` method not in a field clean method

Comment: @IainShelvington, thank you very much, I will post the code with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, using clean method.

```
# forms.py    
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    start = cleaned_data.get('start')
    end = cleaned_data.get('end')
    active = cleaned_data.get('active')

    if end < start:
        raise forms.ValidationError('end date cannot be less than start date.')
    if end and active:
        raise forms.ValidationError('active employee should cannot be end date.')
        
 # template.html
 
 {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{error}}
{% endfor %}
```